# Printing an image for each object in an array with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty new to React Native and got stuck on a personal project trying to utilize Instagram's API. I'm currently using a forEach to try to return an Image for every object in an array and it doesn't seem like I can get the Image to show up. When I do a console.log(images.images.thumbnail.url) within the mediaPrinter function, I do see that all the urls are being logged.

Here's the API call:

```
export default function ApiCall() {
  return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        return json.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}
```

And the rest of the relevant code:

```
mediaPage() {
  return <ScrollView style={styles.scrollBody}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Browse Through Our Moments
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.imageRow}>
        {this.mediaHandler()}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
}

mediaHandler() {
  ApiCall()
    .then((data) => {
      this.mediaPrinter(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}

mediaPrinter(array) {
  array.forEach(function(images) {
    return <Image
      source={{uri: images.images.thumbnail.url}}
      style={{width: 138, height: 138}} />
  })
}
```

I was also wondering if there was a way to resize the images responsively using React Native's currently provided resources.

Comment: to resize the images responsively use the view height and view width( 'vh' and 'vw' respectively) css units. they take a percentage of the entire view so  50vw would be 50 percent of the view width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the tirck:

```js
class renderImages extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      images: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount () {
    this.mediaHandler()
  }
  
  mediaPage() {
  return <ScrollView style={styles.scrollBody}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Browse Through Our Moments
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.imageRow}>
        {this.mediaPrinter(this.state.images)}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
}

mediaHandler() {
  ApiCall()
    .then((data) => {
    this.setState({images: data})
      //this.mediaPrinter(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}

mediaPrinter(array) {
  return array.map(function(images, index) {
    // don't put your key as index, choose other unique values as your key.
    return <Image
      key={index}
      source={{uri: images.images.thumbnail.url}}
      style={{width: 138, height: 138}} />
  })
}

}
```

The function you called inside the `<View style={styles.imageRow}></View>` should return jsx to be rendered. As you can see, in your approach, you are returning nothing.

In the solution above, I have set the state when medialHandler gets data from instagram, which triggers the re-render and the mediaPrinter function is called again with the array of instagram photos data, hence it gets rendered.

Comment: The mediaHandler is never called in your answer and it's setting this.state.images to stay as an empty array. Where would you call the mediaHandler?

Comment: Nevermind, I just called this.mediaHandler inside of mediaPage and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry about that, I think a better place to all it will be on `componentDidMount`.  I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Does React Native allow componentDidMount? Also, do you happen to know why the ApiCall might be calling over and over again? I just did a simple fetch but for some reason, if I leave the app idle, I'll get rate limited by Instagram because the ApiCall repeats..

Comment: Yes, It is based on react, so all of the react APIs are available on react-native. If you call it on componentDidMount, it should be only called once. But if your component is mounting and unmounting and mounting again and so on for some reason, it will be called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

`mediaHandler()` returns promise. React don't know anything about promises. So react can't render your image list.

You should not mix any non-ui logic and rendering inside component. It is bad practice. React ui component should be as stupid as possible. Component should only render ui based on data passed throw `props` (image list in your case) and trigger some events (image click for example). Calling API is work for another part of your code.

There are many possibilities how to write your code. One of them is concept of "clever" (container) and "stupid" (presentation) components.

In your case presentation component will be:

```
class ImageList extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return <ScrollView style={styles.scrollBody}>
             <Text style={styles.welcome}>
               Browse Through Our Moments
             </Text>
             <View style={styles.imageRow}>
               {this.renderImages(this.props.images)}
             </View>
           </ScrollView>;
  }

  renderImages(images) {
    return images.forEach(function(image) {
      return <Image
        source={{uri: image.url}}
        style={{width: 138, height: 138}} />
    })
  }
}
```

And container component:

```
class ImageListContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { images: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ApiCall()
      .then((data) => {
         ...
         this.setState({images: images})
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <ImageList images={this.state.images} />;
  }
}
```

More info you can find here https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.r8c3p0540 and here https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.65028sqwh

Another option is using redux, flux, rx or whatever you want. React provides only presentation layer.

Comment: I get what you mean about "React don't know anything about promises", but it's a bit confusing. You can use promises in react code, but you can't use them as jsx is what I think you mean.

Comment: You are using promises in javascript code. It is more correct. And you are right that react can't automatic handle promises in jsx. It is not his job.

Comment: I can't really use componentDidMount since this is React Native.. but this was still informative!

Comment: No differences. React is a part of react native ecosystem. Your component is still react component so it has all react methods.